# What is the name for this generalization of a category?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Is there a name for an object which is made of a set of objects, and a set of arrows which can be from objects/arrows to objects/arrows (all four combinations)?

Equivalently, this is a category where each arrow is identified with a unique object in the category.

Comment: Something like the comma category?  Or are you thinking of something like 2-categories?

Comment: It's not a 2-category (or even $\omega$-category), since those don't allow arrows from objects to other arrows, for example.

Comment: @Stefan wouldn't you get what you want if you consider the identity arrow on some object as that object? So an arrow from an object $A$ to an arrow $f$ would actually be an arrow from $Id_A$ to $f$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma What object do you assign to a *non*-identity arrow, and how do you make sense of an arrow from an arrow to an arrow?

Comment: It seems like what you want is the arrow category of a category $C$, often denoted $\operatorname{Mor}(C)$. This is equivalently the category of functors $[2,C]$ where $2$ is the category with two objects and one morphism between them.

Comment: @asdq How does that give you the identification (arrow to unique object) the OP wants?

Comment: @Noah I was thinking in terms of the category of arrows as suggested by asdq, or a 2-category. Then we would only need to find a way to interpret an arrow from an object to an arrow (and the other direction).

Comment: @Noah Schweber Perhaps I was misunderstanding the OP, I thought he wanted to start with a category and construct something new where we allow morphisms between morphisms of the original category. But if you want to allow arrows between the morphisms in the new category too, then my suggestion does not work and one should probably resort to something like $\infty$-categories.

Comment: @MarkKamsma From the OP: "Equivalently, this is a category where each arrow is identified with a unique object in the category."

Comment: @asdq From the OP: "Equivalently, this is a category where each arrow is identified with a unique object in the category."

Comment: Also relevant: "...**all four combinations**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Noah Ah yes, now I wonder if you can make sense of repeating this construction. Something like taking the category of arrows every time (in which the original category embeds) and then taking the union. Of course this wouldn't give a name the OP was asking for, but it's still related.

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect (OP: am I right?) that the motivating example is the category of sets. A function between sets, after all, is itself a set (namely, an ordered pair consisting of a set of ordered pairs - the graph of the function - and the codomain). That said, I can't think of a "geometric" or "algebraic" example, so I suspect this isn't really a well-studied (or named) concept (although I've certain seen it crop up in conversations around categorical set theory).

Comment: Well, it seems any $\omega$-category gives rise to a natural such generalized category: namely, take all $n$-cells to be separate objects.

Comment: And can you 'compose' those arrows? Would you write more specific examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It echoes with the [generalized categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02885) of Lucius Schoenbaum. Basically it takes the unisorted presentation of category theory and drops the requirement that $ss=st=s$ and $tt=ts=t$ (where $s$ is the source map and $t$ the target map).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Let $\text{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$ be the category of morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$. Perhaps what you want is simply a category $\mathcal{C}$ equipped with a "nice" functor $F: \text{Arr}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$. Then, for instance, if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, then $\alpha : F(f)\to F(g)$ is a morphism between morphisms.